# ¿Cómo saber cómo se pronuncian los extranjerismos crudos?

Tags: pronunciación, extranjerismos

En la página de la RAE sobre los [extranjerismos](http://www.rae.es/diccionario-panhispanico-de-dudas/que-contiene/tratamiento-de-los-extranjerismos) se indica (énfasis mío):

> 2.1. Mantenimiento de la grafía y pronunciación originarias. Se trata de extranjerismos asentados en el uso internacional en su forma original, como *ballet*, *blues*, *jazz* o *software*. En este caso se advierte de su condición de extranjerismos crudos y de la obligación de escribirlos con resalte tipográfico (cursiva o comillas) para señalar su carácter ajeno a la ortografía del español, hecho que explica que **su pronunciación no se corresponda con su forma escrita**.

Si no se conoce previamente la pronunciación de la palabra, y por el resalte tipográfico se sabe que su pronunciación no se corresponde con su forma escrita, ¿cómo se sabe cuál es la pronunciación correcta? Porque el DLE no la indica, limitándose a decir si es una voz inglesa o francesa o alemana ...

Answer (score 1):

Obviamente si de antemano se sabe que la forma como está escrita la palabra no es la que fonéticamente corresponde a la pronunciación del español entonces solo quedan dos opciones. O conocer del idioma original desde el que se tomó el extranjerismo o consultar alguna fuente.

En caso de que sean extranjerismos ya adoptados por la RAE entonces se buscan en el diccionario de la RAE. Ej:

> [ballet](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=ballet) 1. Voz francesa (pron. [balé]) que significa ‘danza clásica’ y...

Como el extranjerismo ya ha sido adoptado y se encuentra en el diccionario vamos a donde dice **(pron. [])** y encontramos cómo se pronuncia usando la escritura y pronunciación del español. En este caso **balé**

Para los ejemplos en tu pregunta el único que no tiene la pronunciación explícitamente definida en el DPD es *software*. Para los demás la RAE define la forma de pronunciarlos.

http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=blues
http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=jazz
http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=ballet
http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=software

Comment: Si. Tienes razón. Esos diccionarios siempre serán "trabajo en progreso". No alcanzan a mantener actualizados los modismos que genera el propio español en las diversas regiones, mucho menos van a poder mantenerse al día con la infinita cantidad de neologismos, extranjerismos y demás influencias externas.

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente en aquellos casos, no hay una pronunciación asentada en el idioma, por lo tanto, se escucha varias cosas.

Tomando un par de ejemplos:

- **wifi**
  Hay los que dicen *güifi*, *guáifay*, *huifi* y *huáifay*.
- **jazz**
  Algunos dicen *yas* o *chas*, y otros imitan variablemente la *j*, *a* o *z* inglesa.
- **ballet**
  Unos dicen *balet*, otros *balé*

Sin que exista una pronunciación estable o estándar, no se puede dar indicaciones de pronunciación.  Pero en el caso de que sí, lo marcan, como indica [la respuesta de DGaleano](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/25747/4182).

Comment: Me parece muy bien. No hay una regla. Hay lo que le gente dice.

Answer (score 0):

Pues si la RAE no da una grabación ni símbolos fonéticos, entonces hay que probar otra fuente.  Probé dos opciones:

1. Busqué en Youtube y sí, encontré un canal que ofrece grabaciones de muchas palabras, incluyendo *software* -- pero excluyendo *lied*.  El estilo de presentación es bastante chocante.  https://youtu.be/VERADco3_vQ
2. Se puede usar Google Translate si no dejas que autodetecte el idioma del input, es decir si indicas que la palabra que escribes es del español.  Luego haces clic en el micrófono (a mano izquierda) y ya.

   Una desventaja de este método: sólo se presenta una variante.

   Las palabras que probé salieron muy bien con la excepción de *lied*.  La máquina tomó esta palabra por algo que proviene del inglés, no del alemán, incluso cuando puse "el cantante empezó con un lied."  En contraste, le salió mejor cuando puse "el cantante empezó con tres lieder," aunque irracionalmente usó acento de inglés para la R de *lieder*.