# ¿Qué reglas de acentuación y pronunciación se usan en los préstamos lingüísticos?

Tags: ortografía, pronunciación, acentuación, préstamo-lingüístico

Supongamos que uso un préstamo lingüístico, por ejemplo:

> Estoy ahora adentro del car

En este caso una palabra en inglés, rodeada de palabras en español en una oración.

¿Aplico las reglas de acentuación del español o del inglés? ¿Uso el "sentence stress" o "word stress" del inglés o uso las diferentes formas de acentuación del español?

Comment: No creo que sea un buen exemplo. Y tampoco creo que importa a menos de ser una redacción formal and cuyo caso, hay que haber una buena razón para car en vez de coche o carro.

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Cómo saber cómo se pronuncian los extranjerismos crudos?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/25746/1674).

Answer (score 6):

Si se usan extranjerismos crudos en un texto, estos se deben escribir en cursiva y tal y como se escriban en su idioma original, incluyendo las marcas de acentuación que tengan en su idioma. En tu caso, sería así:

> Estoy ahora dentro del *car*.

Aunque otro ejemplo podría ser este, que incluye una palabra que en su idioma original (francés) contiene tres marcas de acentuación:

> A mí solo me gusta la leche *écrémé*.

Si adaptas la palabra extranjera a nuestras reglas de pronunciación, entonces tienes un extranjerismo adaptado, y no solo habría que adaptar las marcas de acentuación, sino toda la palabra. Como ejemplo, el caso de *football* que se adaptó como *fútbol*, cambiando la grafía y añadiendo el correspondiente acento como palabra llana acabada en *-l*. En este caso ya no se escribiría en cursiva, sino en redonda.

Comment: Los Mexicanos dicen closet para armario y no hacen nada así.

Comment: @Lambie porque es extranjerismo adaptado: [clóset](https://dle.rae.es/clóset).

Comment: Lo sé. Pero no sé en que contexto *que no sea muy formal* se tiendria uno que poner italicos. :)

Comment: @Lambie pues supongo que artículos periodísticos, textos literarios y jurídicos, artículos científicos, _posts_ aquí en el sitio de español, cosas por el estilo. Si vas a escribir un correo a tus compañeros de trabajo pues no te vas a liar a escribir extranjerismos con cursiva, desde luego. Pero eso podría ser otra pregunta interesante: ¿en qué contextos se recomienda seguir todas las pautas de la RAE?